# Do new Dropbox users no longer get a "Top Secret.txt" file by default?

Tags: dropbox

When I installed Dropbox many years ago, it loaded some files into your account by default. One of these files was "Top Secret.txt".

Since then, Dropbox has changed the way the "Public" folder works. So the related "Top Secret.txt" file may no longer be distributed...

When I checked with someone else: they had the original "/Photos/Pensive Parakeet.jpg," but not "/Public/Top Secret.txt". The only file they had was "/Public/how to use the public folder.rtf" (Which I don't have.)

I'm looking for a text file all/most Dropbox users should have so they can test my Dropbox app with minimal fuss.

Answer (score 1):

> Public folders have been depreciated I'm afraid John-Kim so accounts
>   are no longer created with them.

source: [Dropbox forums](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Missing-files-and-folders/Top-Secret-txt-file-no-longer-in-set-of-default-Dropbox-files/m-p/193266/highlight/true#M8101)

---

I worked around my issue by integrating with the [Dropbox Chooser dropin](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser) so users can select from files that exist in their account.